# Обновление БД. Библиотека Sqlite-asset-helper

Tags: android, sqlite

Я использую библиотеку [android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) 
Необходимо обновить БД, но так, чтобы пользователь сохранил данные. Имена таблиц, столбцы остались прежними. Только количество записей в таблицах увеличилось.

Версия БД увеличена. Как указано в README, создан файл - info.db_upgrade_1-2.sql

```
ALTER TABLE "poems_table" RENAME TO 'poems_table_TMP';
 CREATE TABLE
        "poems_table" ( "id" INTEGERL, "title" text, "poem" text,
        "subject" text, "years" text, "favorite" INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY ("id") );

        INSERT INTO "poems_table"  ("id", "title", "poem", "subject",
        "years", "favorite") SELECT "id", "title", "poem", "subject",
        "years", "favorite" FROM "poems_table_TMP";
 DROP TABLE
        "poems_table_TMP";
```

код DBHelpera

```
public class PoemsDbHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static String DB_NAME = "info.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

public PoemsDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}


public Cursor getPoems_table() {
  //  SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
   // db.close();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect = {"id", "title", "poem", "subject", "years", "favorite"};
    String sqlTables = "poems_table";

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;

}
```

Закомментированная часть - это решение подобной проблемы как у меня (найдено на просторах SO). Мне не помогло.

Приложение запускается, но отображаются старые данные

Comment: Как я это понимаю, если вы добавили данных только в одну таблицу, вам надо в скрипте northwind.db_upgrade_1-2.sql прописать команду для sqlite - update для конкретной table.... Могу быть не прав.

Comment: если вы несколько раз изменяли скрипт обновления, то посмотрите, какая у вас сейчас версия базы данных на тестирующем устройстве. Дело в том, что обновление базы происходит только при повышении версии и могло быть так, что повышение версии произошло, а скрипт обновления в первый раз был некорректный, после исправления скрипта изменения применятся уже не будут, так как версия базы 2 и обновление не требуется (нужно повышать еще версию)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для обновления БД без потери данных с использованием данной библиотеки можно пойти двумя путями: создать текстовый файл .sql и прописать там скрипт или же переопределить метод onUpgrade. Коллеги с enSO помогли мне решить данную задачу вторым способом. Т.к. на ruSO ответа не нашлось, я выложу перевод рабочего решения.

БД должна лежать в директории assets/databases.

При повышении версии копируем обновленную базу данных в виде отдельной(временной) базы данных и затем копируем строки из нее в существующую базу данных (если это несуществующие строки).

```
 public class PoemsDbHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "brodsky.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "poems_table";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_POEM = "poem";
    public static final String COLUMN_SUBJECT = "subject";
    public static final String COLUMN_YEARS = "years";
    public static final String COLUMN_FAVORITE = "favorite";

    Context mContext;

    public PoemsDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
       mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(newVersion > oldVersion)
        getNewPoems(mContext, db); // <<<<<< получаем новые записи при обновлении
    }


    private void getNewPoems(Context context, SQLiteDatabase db) {
 // Подготовка к копированию обновленной базы данных из папки ресурсов
        InputStream is;
        OutputStream os;
        final String tempNewDbName = "temp_brodsky.db";
        int buffer_size = 4096;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
        String newDBPath = context.getDatabasePath(tempNewDbName).getPath();


        File newDBFile = new File(newDBPath);
    // Если скопированная версия обновленной базы данных существует, удаляем ее
        if (newDBFile.exists()) {
            newDBFile.delete();
        }

        File newDBFileDirectory = newDBFile.getParentFile();
       // На всякий случай создаем каталог баз данных
        if (!newDBFileDirectory.exists()) {
            newDBFileDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            is = context.getAssets().open("databases/" + DB_NAME);
            os = new FileOutputStream(newDBFile);
            int bytes_read;
            while ((bytes_read = is.read(buffer,0, buffer_size)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer);
            }
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            is.close();

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Ouch updated database not copied - processing stopped - see stack-trace above.");
        }

        long id = maxId(db) + 1;  // Получаем следующий доступный id
        SQLiteDatabase newDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(newDBFile.getPath(),null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        Cursor csr = newDB.query(TABLE_NAME, null,null,null,null,null,null);
        long insert_result;
        db.beginTransaction();
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            insert_result = insertCorePoem(
                    db,
                    id,
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TITLE)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_POEM)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SUBJECT)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_YEARS)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FAVORITE))
            );
        // Если строка была вставлена, то увеличиваем идентификатор
        // Если не вставлена (результат = -2), тогда оставить идентификатор как есть, так как он не использовался
            if (insert_result > 0) {
                id++;
            }

        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
        csr.close();
        newDBFile.delete();  // Удаляем скопированную базу данных, она больше не требуется
    }

    public long insertCorePoem(SQLiteDatabase db, long id, String title, String poem, String subject, String years, String favorite) {

        String whereClause = COLUMN_TITLE + "=? AND " + COLUMN_POEM + "=? AND " + COLUMN_SUBJECT + "=? AND " + COLUMN_YEARS + "=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[]{
                title,
                poem,
                subject,
                years
        };

        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null, whereClause, whereArgs,null,null,null);
        boolean rowExists = (csr.getCount() > 0);
        csr.close();
        if (rowExists) {
            Log.d("INSERTCOREPOEM","Skipping insert of row");
            return -2;
        }

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_ID, id);
        cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(COLUMN_POEM, poem);
        cv.put(COLUMN_SUBJECT, subject);
        cv.put(COLUMN_YEARS, years);
        cv.put(COLUMN_FAVORITE, favorite);
        Log.d("INSERTCOREPOEM","Inserting new column with id " + String.valueOf(id));
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }

    private long maxId(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        long rv = 0;
        String extractColumn = "maxid";
        String[] col = new String[]{"max(" + COLUMN_ID + ") AS " + extractColumn};
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,col,null,null,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(extractColumn));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
 // метод возвращает курсор, который используем в нужной активити
 public Cursor getAllPoems() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(NAME_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
PoemsDbHelper mDBHlpr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDBHlpr = new PoemsDbHelper(this);
    Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getAllPoems();
    ..........
    ..........
    csr.close();
}
```

}

Comment: что то похоже на костыль какой то .. чтобы все это сделать, никакая специальная библиотека вообще не нужна. все то же самое можно (и нужно) проделать в стандартном SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: ну да. только лишь с SQLiteOpenHelper будет больше кода

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сделал по инструкции. Всё понятно, всё работает!

Answer (score 0):

Это всего лишь переведенная часть файла README

Генерация скриптов обновления

Вы можете использовать сторонние инструменты для автоматической генерации SQL, необходимого для изменения базы данных из одной версии схемы в другую. Одним из таких приложений является SQLite Compare Utility для Windows.

Обновления через перезапись

Если у вас есть база данных, доступная только для чтения, или вы не заботитесь о потере пользовательских данных, вы можете принудительно заставлять пользователей использовать последнюю версию базы данных SQLite при каждом увеличении номера версии (перезаписывая локальную базу данных той, которая находится в активах), вызывая setForcedUpgrade()метод в вашем SQLiteAsstHelperконструкторе подкласса.

Вы можете дополнительно передать аргумент, который является номером версии, ниже которого обновление будет принудительно выполнено.

Обратите внимание, что это перезапишет существующую локальную базу данных и все данные в ней.

Comment: Я пользуюсь сторонним инструментом SQLite Compare, с помощью которого и создано -  CREATE TABLE
        "poems_table" ( "id" INTEGERL, "title" text, "poem" text,
        "subject" text, "years" text, "favorite" INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY ("id") );    И пользовательские данные нельзя терять.. В таблицах есть колонки с избранным

Comment: @Евгений Каршицкий отпишите , как найдете решение, тоже интересно.

Comment: Если еще актуально, решение выложил